# how to set default initial value on nz-autocomplete

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

How to set initial object value using `compareWith`.

copied same code from [docs](https://ng.ant.design/components/auto-complete/en) yet unable to set initial value.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-wwpebj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[compareWith]` feature is only available from **[version 9](https://ng.ant.design/version/9.3.x/components/auto-complete/en#nz-autocomplete)**.

From provided StackBlitz, you are using **ng-zorro-antd version 8** and the [docs](https://ng.ant.design/version/8.5.x/components/auto-complete/en#nz-autocomplete) didn't mention any info on `[compareWith]` feature.

---

### Solution

By **upgrading ng-zorro-antd to version 9 and above**, you will be able to initialize the default value (with object) to `nzAutocomplete`.

**Pre-requisite:**

[Angular Support](https://ng.ant.design/version/9.3.x/docs/introduce/en#angular-support)

> ng-zorro-antd keeps the same major version with @angular/core, now supports Angular ^9.0.0

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://ng-zorro-antd-start-ddmnqu.stackblitz.io)

Comment: my bad !! blunder from my side.